# Convert timestamp in linux

Tags: linux, centos, timestamp, centos7, unix-timestamp

I have a date represented as 1231533845

I understand that is supposed to be Fri Jan  9 15:44:05 EST 2009

And that on OSX it can be decoded with:
date -j -f %s 1231533845

What's the equivalent command on linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will use the date function, but with the option -d
`date -d @1231533845`

Comment: Tried everything buy the @.  Thank you.